# How can I open a new file while my android application is still in background?

Tags: android, oncreate

When "closed" MyApp save its new data in `my_file.json (MODE_PRIVATE)`, and it can open `other_file.json` from file manager or when received by bluetooth.

The issue is it fails to open the new file if MyApp is still in "background".
I want to know what the best place is to implement the opening process.
right now I do it in `OnCreate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    ...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    Uri fileUri = null;

    if (Intent.ACTION_EDIT.equals(action) || Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        fileUri = intent.getData();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("text/"))
            fileUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    }
    //NB: if fileUri == null load the data from the old saved file
    // otherwise from the Uri
    MySingleton.get(this, fileUri);
}
```

thanks

Comment: If you want do something in background, use service

Comment: Clarification: "Background" I mean when I press back button twice to close it leaving android to decide to destroy  it or to keep it.

Comment: I don't get you but **background** means **when your application is closed.**  Service would run even though.

Comment: Do you mean when your app is going from foreground to background? If so, I think onPause would be the method you need. On the contrary, passing from background to foreground, you should be putting your code inside onResume

Comment: ...I saved the the updated state of the data  to my private file in onPause, and after I close MyApp by clicking back button twice -not the home button- and opened a new file using file manger MyApp lunched again but it fail to open this new file and keep the old data that I have save. but if I close it and manually remove myApp from the "back stack" and open a new file, now the data in this file can be loaded!